# Update two table row from a post value

Tags: php, mysql

I have here two tables, I need to update both table row field from a post value. table1.item and table2.item update from post value. I didn't know how to set both table field equal to post value.
Any help will appreciate.

**Table1**

```
| pr_id | item |
----------------
| 1001  | pen  |
```

**Table2**

```
| pr_id | item |
----------------
| 1001  | pen  |
```

**Query**

```
<?php
$pr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["pr_id"]);
$item= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["item"]);

$mysqli->query("UPDATE table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.pr_id = table2.pr_id WHERE table1 .pr_id = '$pr' ");

?>
```

Comment: You want to update item or pr_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Query:

```
UPDATE table1 T1 LEFT JOIN 
       table2 T2 ON T1.pr_id = T2.pr_id 
SET T1.Item= '$item', T2.Item = '$item' 
WHERE T1.pr_id = '$pr'
```

With php:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table1 T1 LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.pr_id = T2.pr_id SET T1.Item= '$item', T2.Item = '$item' WHERE T1.pr_id = '$pr' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update table1 inner join table2
    on table1.pr_id=table2.pr_id 
    //your changes 
    set table1.item ='some thing', table2.item ='some thing'
    where table2 .pr_id ='$pr' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion it is better to use Compound Trigger for updating 2 diffenent tables at the same time. Try to use that.